# Get elements of a matrix that are greater than sum of their two indices in row major order

Tags: arrays, matlab, for-loop, matrix

I'm Writing a function called `large_elements` that takes input an array named `X` that is a matrix or a vector. The function identifies those elements of `X` that are greater than the sum of their two indexes.

For example, if the element `X(2,3)` is `6`, then that element would be identified because `6 > (2 + 3)`. The output of the function gives the indexes(row and column sub) of such elements found in **row-major order**. It is a matrix with exactly two columns. The first column contains the row indexes, while the second column contains the corresponding column indexes.

Here is an example, the statement

```
indexes = large_elements([1 4; 5 2; 6 0])
```

should give the output like this:

```
[1 2; 2 1; 3 1]
```

If no such element exists,
the function returns an
`empty array`.

I have came up with the following code

```
function indexes = large_elements(A)
    [r c] = size(A);
    ind = 1;
    for ii = 1:r
        for jj = 1:c
            if A(ii,jj) > ii + jj
                indexes(ind,:) = [ii jj];
                ind = ind + 1;
            else
                indexes = [];
            end
       end  
    end
end
```

But the results are not as expected. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: i have updated the code, error for argument(s) [10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1]
output should be [1 1;1 2;1 3;1 4]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One vectorised approch using [`bsxfun`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html), [`find`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) and [`ind2sub`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ind2sub.html)

```
A = randi(8,5);    %// Your matrix

%// finding sum of the indexes for all elements
indSum = bsxfun(@plus, (1:size(A,1)).', 1:size(A,2));

%// generating a mask of which elements satisfies the given condition (i.e A > indSum)
%// Transposing the mask and finding corresponding indexes
[c,r] = find(bsxfun(@gt, A, indSum).') ;

%// getting the matrix by appending row subs and col subs
out = [r,c]
```

**Results:**

**Input A:**

```
>> A

A =

 4     4     7     2     2
 1     3     4     8     3
 8     8     2     8     7
 8     3     4     5     1
 4     1     1     1     1
```

**Output in row-major order:**

```
out =

 1     1
 1     2
 1     3
 2     4
 3     1
 3     2
 3     4
 4     1
```

**Note:** Getting subs in row-major order is tricky here

---

Also here is your correct loopy approach

```
[r, c] = size(A);
ind = 0;
indexes = [];
for ii = 1:r
    for jj = 1:c
        if A(ii,jj) > ii + jj
            ind = ind + 1;
            indexes(ind,:) = [ii jj];              
        end
   end  
end
```

Comment: Nice, but you can skip the call to `ind2sum` altogether by calling find on the result of `bsxfun` call which return the indices already in matrix of `logical`. Like that: `[c,r] = find( bsxfun(@gt, A, indSum).' ) ;`

Comment: @Hoki, Ah! I totally forgot that you could generate row and column sub from `find` itself.. Thanks for correcting me :) Edited!!

Answer (score 0):

That is because whenever you encounter an element which is smaller than the sum of its indices you are reinitializing the array to `null`. So the output is coming out to be `null`. You should not initialize it to `null` on the `else` condition.

Comment: then what could be possible way

Comment: Don't put the `indexes = [];` in the `else` part. Put it at the end if your `ind` is still 1 after the loop